# How to emit event from component loop to main parent angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components, angular2-directives

I wrote the below code, where I am looping component to display children

**parent.component.ts**

```
 tree = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'test 1'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'test 2',
      children: [
        {
           id: 3,
           name: 'test 3'
        }
      ]
    }
 ]

nodeClicked(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-child [tree]="tree" (nodeEmitter)="nodeClicked($event)"></app-child>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Input() tree;
@Output() nodeEmitter = new EventEmitter();

clickToEmit() {
    this.nodeEmitter.emit(1);
}
```

**child.component.html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let node of tree">{{ node.name }}</li>
  <button (click)="clickToEmit()">Click Me!!!</button>
  <app-child [tree]="node.children" (nodeEmitter)="nodeClicked($event)"></app-child>
</ul>
```

Here, my problem is

- I am able to get emitted event in **parent.component.html**
- I am not able to get emitted event from **child.component.html** to
  **parent.component.html**

I am getting the error as **nodeClicked** is not defined in **child.component.ts**

What I am doing wrong here? I wasted so many hours of time on this issue.

Thank you for your help... :-)

Comment: you dont need this `<app-child [tree]="node.children" (nodeEmitter)="nodeClicked($event)"></app-child>` in your child.component.html

Comment: and you are getting that error because nodeClicked() function is not defined in child.component.ts

Comment: Then how can I get emitted event data from sub sub childs? Can you please provide the answer, I didn't get you. Sorry!!!

Comment: @TeddySterne has already mentioned in his answer, you can check. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the child component you need to continue chaining the event up to the parent. Modify your template so that the emitter re-emits when a child event occurs.

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let node of tree">{{ node.name }}</li>
  <button (click)="clickToEmit()">Click Me!!!</button>
  <app-child [tree]="node.children" (nodeEmitter)="nodeEmitter.emit($event)"></app-child>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! @Teddy Sterne, your answer is working. But two times the event is getting emitted. Do you know, what will be the issue? Thank you again...

Comment: The template event binding is just passing the event up the chain of components but all events originate from `clickToEmit` method. This makes sense because there are several nested instances of the `ChildComponent`.